# Change Text Color of a Specific Character

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

Currently I m using TextView. I need to change the color of specific character in a string , as i have to work with **localization** so **SpannableString** won`t help me that much.

The string may be like this ***Hello please select at least 1 to move on*** now i would to change the text of just this specific "1" so that if it is converted to other language like french dutch the color of "1" wont get disturb with respect to its indexing.

How can i achieve this

P.S   String is coming from `R.String`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check this out:

```
myMsg.setText("Hello please select at least" +  Html.fromHtml("<font color='#FF0000'><b>1</b></font>"+"to move on"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your specific character is always the same in the different languages, you can use `String.indexOf(String string)` to get the position of the character and than use `Spannable`to format the String.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use ForegroundColorSpan, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html